# Akka-Java Routing Issue

Tags: java, akka

I have the following issue in Akka-Java.

I have one Parent Actor `MainActor.class` and this parent has 5 child routes. Following is the hierarchy:

`My App => Main Actor => [Child Route-1,Child-Route-2,..]`

Simple Use case is String input is parsed to Integer as output:

`MyApp ===ask[string input]===> Main Actor ==route==> Child(parses to Integer) === integer result===> Main Actor ===result==> MyApp`

Here is the Main Actor snippet:

```
class MainActor extends UntypedActor {
 Router router; {
  // ...routes are configured here
 }

 public void onReceive(Object message) {
  if (message instanceof String) {
   router.route(message, self()); // route it to child
  } else if (message instanceof Integer) {
   // received from child, 'tell' this result to actual sender/parent i.e, MyApp
   sender().tell(message, self());
  } else unhandled(message);
 }
}
```

And Child Actor does nothing but String parsing to Integer and takes the result and sends it back to it's sender by `sender().tell(result,getContext().parent())`

**Issue**

`MainActor` is sending the Parsed integer result sent by child back to child itself instead of `MyApp`. I also tried replacing `sender()` to `getContext().parent()` in `MainActor` but still it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you receive Integers from a child actor of MainActor, the sender points to the child actor.
When you invoke `tell` on sender it returns the message back to the child actor.

This should work:
`getContext().parent().tell(message, self())`

Comment: I tried replacing `sender()` to `getContext().parent()` as I mentioned in the post, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

You can either go directly from your child to your app (bypassing the root actor on the way back), by forwarding the message (see the self() -> sender() change):

```
if (message instanceof String) {
  router.route(message, sender());
}
```

So when the child responds, his sender is now the app instead of the root.

Alternatively, you can use futures, [the ask/pipe patten](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors) in particular

Answer (score 0):

You should really go with [Diego Martinola 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680137/3371051).

The reason why your code isn't working is the following:

- when you use `sender().tell(message, self)`, `sender()` is not MainApp, because `sender()` gives you the sender of the message you are currently processing. Since you are processing the Integer message from the child actor, the effect is you are sending the message back to it.
- The modification you tried, i.e. `getContext().parent().tell(message, self)` is no good either. In this case you are sending to the parent of MainActor, not to MainApp. Actually I suspect MainApp is not even an actor, right? You can only send messages to actors. If your intention was sending back to the actor who sent the initial message to MainActor, keep in mind this is not MainApp, it is a temporary actor used by `Patterns.ask`. Regardless, the main point is that, in the handler of the Integer message, you have no way to get an ActorRef of that temporary actor, cause as said before, `sender()` gives the sender of the current message. A workaround could be getting the sender in the handler of the String message and storing it in variable for later, like this:

  ```
  class MainActor extends UntypedActor {
   ActorRef lastRequester;
   Router router; {
    // ...routes are configured here
   }

   public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof String) {
     lastRequester = sender();
     router.route(message, self()); // route it to child
    } else if (message instanceof Integer) {
     lastRequester.tell(message, self());
    } else unhandled(message);
   }
  }
  ```

But this is dangerous, since you would be relying on all Integer messages arriving before the next String message; if an Integer message for the first String message arrives after the second String message, it will be sent to the actor who send the second String. Waiting for all childs to answer is not really an option because Akka gives you at-most-once delivery semantics. You would have to create a mechanism to recognize what String message a certain Integer message is associated to and keep a list of `ActorRef` instead of a single one.

While the latter is not terribly complicated to implement, it is not really worth it for your use case, and I would say in most routing scenarios, [Diego Martinola 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680137/3371051) is the way to go.